# Designing a Generic Form in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, generics, visual-studio-2012

I have about 6 classes that all inherit from the same base class. I am making a user interface to allow the user to edit these classes, and then persist them to a database. I can get all of the code to work great, if I could only use generics.

Once I try to make the form generic, there are some serious problems. I've read a few solutions, like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/afdfce40-8d7a-4300-bd8d-26e18c320a71/designer-error-with-descendant-of-generic-form?forum=winformsdesigner but they don't really seem to work. All this does is get me a form that is designed - but not usable with generics, and an empty form class with generics that it inherited from.

I need a form that I can edit in the designer, and construct with a generic type in my program and it maintains all the design and code from the one in the designer.

Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried passing the base class as a parameter in the form's constructor?  That should allow you to pass the inherited classes to the form.  However, if I'm not mistaken, only the base class properties will be exposed to the form.  If you don't expect to change your inherited classes very much, an enum and a select block might work to cast the class to the inherited type.

Comment: `Does anyone have a working solution for this?` - Yes, it's called [WPF](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/).

Comment: hmm - maybe you will have to create a generic proxy object and then manyally initiise form instances from them ... manually writing properties from the generic into the form ... but it will be far from fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the solution shown in the article I linked is correct, but it's just confusing to follow.

I figured I would post my answer to help someone else who might have this issue.

**Scenario:**
You have a form that you need to be able to use with Generics (i.e. pass in a type to use for some special things). The main benefit of this is using the designer to do all the code to generate your form.

My scenario was a basic GUI to edit some objects that all inherited from the same parent. The form consists of a Add, Remove, and Save button, and a DGV that the objects are bound to. Instead of duplicating the form N time and strongly typing it, you can use generics.

**Solution**
Design your first form in the designer. You can put any non-generic code here you like. For me though, I have a file that is strictly designer code:

*NonGenericLookupForm.vb*

```
Public Class NonGenericLookupForm   

End Class
```

The designer code file for this form will have all of your controls.

Then create another file that inherits from this form:

*GenericLookupForm.vb*

```
Public Class GenericLookupForm(Of T As {LookupItem, New})
    Inherits NonGenericLookupForm

    Private lookupItems as List(of T)

    ' Other code here. You can handle events from the inherited form

End Class
```

And finally, you can create this form with your type:

```
Dim SpecificLookupEditor as New GenericLookupForm(of SpecificLookupType)
SpecificLookupEditor.ShowDialog()
```